# Print output Mat from sobel (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to know the right type of the variables stored at the output of sobel (x in my case). When I run this code

```
Mat x;
Sobel( input, x, CV_32F, 1, 0);
for(int i=0;i<input.cols;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<input.rows;j++){
        printf("%f\n",x.at<float>(i,j));
    }
}
```

I'm getting something like

```
213918711808.000000, 885887336448.000000 0.000000 0.000169 0.000000
```

But when I run

```
Mat x;
Sobel( input, x, CV_32F, 1, 0);
std::cout<<x<<endl;
```

I get this result (this one is correct)

```
2, 0, 2, 4, 2, -6, -4, 0, -6, -10, -10, -34, ...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<s>It is because printf treats %f as double, not float.</s>

I was wrong. I have tried to reproduce your problem and both types of output give me a correct result. Check if x matrix has different size or type, CV_32F is 5.

```
std::cout << x.type() << " " << x.rows << " " << x.cols << " " << std::endl;
std::cout << input.type() << " " << input.rows << " " << input.cols << " " << std::endl;
```

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a way to convert it to a readable format?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the problem was related to "printf" after your answer. The output gives me 5 for both x and input.

Comment: It turns out that I mixed rows with cols at the loop and then it was returning trash. Anyway, thanks for the help!